# How to proceed compiling Parole when dbus-glib-1 was not found on the system?

Tags: github, compilation, dependencies, dbus, libdbus

This is almost my first trial to compile a package on my own on Xubuntu 20.04 x86_64 because I want to add buttons to Parole for playback jump forward or backward 10 seconds.

In order to compile Parole, I downloaded the source code. I unpacked the downloaded file maintaining the folders structure to `~/Downloads/tmp/parole-master`. Then executed `cd` to this directory. Then I called the command `./autogen.sh`. It produced many lines of output, but the last ones were:

```
checking for dbus-glib-1 >= 0.70... not found
*** The required package dbus-glib-1 was not found on your system.
*** Please install dbus-glib-1 (atleast version 0.70) or adjust
*** the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
*** installed the package in a nonstandard prefix so that
*** pkg-config is able to find it.
```

Somewhere I found a proposal, to uses `libdbus-1-dev` if I want to compile things. Therefore I downloaded the package `libdbus-1-dev_1.12.16-2ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb` and installed it with the command

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libdbus-1-dev_1.12.16-2ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb
```

I checked the presence of libdbus-1 with the command `dpkg -l | grep dbus-1` which resulted in

```
ii  libdbus-1-3:amd64                                  1.12.16-2ubuntu2.3                   amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (library)
ii  libdbus-1-dev:amd64                                1.12.16-2ubuntu2.3                   amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (development headers)
```

After executing `./autogen.sh` again, I got the same error messages.

Then I searched where `libdbus-1-dev` is located on my computer. I found a folder with that name at `/usr/share/doc/libdbus-1-dev`. In it were a simple file `copyright` and four links to these 4 gzipped plain ASCII files:

```
• /usr/share/doc/libdbus-1-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
• /usr/share/doc/libdbus-1-dev/NEWS.gz
• /usr/share/doc/libdbus-1-dev/README.gz
• /usr/share/doc/libdbus-1-dev/AUTHORS.gz
```

I issued
`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/share/doc/libdbus-1-dev`
but this did not change the outcome of a subsequent `./autogen.sh`.

Later I learned from https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable that the environment variable specifies additional paths in which `pkg-config` will search for its `.pc` files. Therefore I issued `find / -type f -name *dbus*.pc 2>/dev/null` and among the outcome of it I found

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/dbus-1.pc
```

which is on the default search path according to `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config` on my computer. I conclude from it that   I should `unset PKG_CONFIG_PATH`  and I repeated `./autogen.sh` but it gave me exactly the same error messages at the end.

**From where can I download the right version of `dbus-glib-1`?**

**How do I have to install it?**